# Probability question about the sequence of letters A,B,C and D

Tags: probability, multinomial-coefficients

I want someone to check if I'm right or not. The problem seems to be easy but everybody knows that not always effortless problems are straightforwardly solvable.

> Given symbols: A, B, C and D and create a 39 symbols sequence out of those four symbols. What's the probability that the 4 A's are in the beggining and in the sequence are 37 A's at all?

My solution: I believe the answer should be $\frac{ 3 \cdot\left( \begin{array}{cc} 35 \\  33,1,1,0 \end{array}\right) + 3 \cdot \left( \begin{array}{cc} 35 \\  33,2,0,0 \end{array}\right) }{4^{39}}$. There are $4^{39}$ combinations at all. . I know it doesn't look nice. Can someone check it or suggest other solution?

Comment: If you use $37$ As in total, including the first $4$ positions of the sequence, shouldn't you have $33$ $A$s in the last $35$ positions?

Comment: Well, the probability that the first four are $A$ is $\left(\frac 14\right)^4$.  So, then we have to get the probability that exactly $33$ of the remaining $35$ are $A$.  That's $\binom {35}{33}\times \left(\frac 14\right)^{33}\times \left( \frac 34\right)^2$.  Now just multiply.

Comment: @lulu I corrected my answer and it seems to be the same as yours. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Lulu...Why did you change the exponent from $\frac{1}{4}^4$ to $\frac{1}{4}^{33}$? Also why are you multiplying by $\frac{3}{4}^2$? Cheers

Comment: @CoreyLevinson  I didn't change any exponent.  I did the problem in two phases: first, the probability that the first four are $A$.  Second, the probability that of the last $35$ exactly $33$ are $A$. The latter is a straight binomial computation.  To get the final answer you need to multiply the two terms.

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense. When you said "Now just multiply", I thought you were implying that the solution was the product of the latter term, not the product of both the former and latter term. It is clear now though.